# Assign input value in all inputs if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a table that fetching rows  from database. Every row contain an input and a checkbox.

After I insert value in the first row and then I click on the checkbox this value is assigned to the all rows below.

But if I start inserting value in the second or the others rows and click the checkbox next to it, the action is not working as it is for the first row.

How can I assign an input value after clicking the checkbox next to it to the all rows below but not the rows above this input ?

Thanks all advance.

```
<table class="table table-striped  tabinp hideal">
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <?php 
  foreach($prices as $row)
  { 
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="price form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input class="put-all-price" type="checkbox"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(".put-all-price").on("click", function() {
    var price = $(".price").val();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.price').each(function() {
        $(this).val(price);
      });
    } else {
      $('.price').each(function() {
        $(this).val("");
      });
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: in your code for every row you are always selecting price from the first row. You can use this:

```
var price = $($(this).parents()[1]).find(".price").val();
```

And second: to iterate over elements that go only **below** you can use *.nextAll()*.

```
$($(this).parents()[3]).nextAll().find(".price").each(function() {
  $(this).val(price);
});
```

Note that *.parents()[index]* depends on your markup.